# World's smallest puzzle

Tags: crosswords

I reproduce here the "world's smallest puzzle" - a crossword etched onto the head of a pin - purportedly created by one Allan Boardman, taken from a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/qRCjjEijJM8?t=135), and to which I don't know the answer.

[image: crossword image]

Can you solve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution appears to be:

> `BB`
>  `BB`
>
>  *King* → Singer and guitarist [B.B. King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B.B._King)
>  *Shot* → [BB gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB_gun) ammunition
>  *50's Star* → [Brigitte Bardot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigitte_Bardot), known as "B.B."

The last clue seems trickier - in the comments, two plausible explanations have been proposed, both based off of a single mistaken letter.

> If the clue is meant to be *Buzz**e**rs* (as proposed by hexomino), then this could be a pun based off of "bees".
>  If the clue is meant to be *Buzzar**d*** (as proposed by Joel Rondeau), then this could be an abbreviation for the common buzzard's Latin binomial, *Buteo buteo*.
>
>  Both of these explanations seem reasonable to me, but there may be a more satisfactory one.

Comment: Looking at the original video, it's conceivable that the clue for 2D is "Buzzers" so probably referring to the associated insects.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that the last clue is rot13("n ohmmneq ersrerapr, nf gur pbzzba ohmmneq vf trahf ohgrb naq fcrpvrf ohgrb, juvpu bs pbhefr, vf fubegrarq gb o.o.")

Comment: Looks like a typo for the last one then.